# How do I check which upgrades I've collected?

Tags: mega-man-x

Is there a way to check which stages I've found the permanent upgrade items for (Body Armor, Heart Tanks, Sub Tanks) in Mega Man X?

I'm trying to collect all the upgrades before completing the game. I know I can visually check how many upgrades I've collected by looking at my health bar size or X's armor, but that doesn't tell me which stages I collected the upgrades in. I'd like to avoid having to recheck every stage for the ones I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

I fear that the only way is your own, hopefully non-volatile - internal memory. The game does not have any form of radar or feature that lists the content of each level. That said, it is also quite easy to just memorize where everything is.

There are just four armor piece: the leg parts is actually unmissable since you are forced to walk thru the capsule in the first place, armor and helmet parts are hidden and miss-able and while the arm part is hidden too the game actually gives you the upgrade for story reasons during the final stages if you haven't get it by then.

The subtank capsules are also just four and should be easy to check for.

The real "problem" are the health upgrades since each stage has one of those. I guess that your only option is to check every stage to see which ones you already got. Luckily they are not that hidden.